# Gardening in windy areas. Is investing in climbers a mistake?

Tags: wind-damage

I have this really ugly looking wall that 8ft tall and runs 18ft long facing south. I really wanna cover it up but im not sure what would be the right option for me. The area gets 12 hours of sun but more importantly, strong winds. I had planted a few plants a year before, all of which are now tilted towards the east because of the strong winds blowing from the west. I was gonna go with a climber but now im not so sure. Perhaps a shrub or a hedge might be the smarter choice here, idk. What would grow best under such conditions?

Comment: define windy, because Mount Washington wind speeds are nothing to joke about, and plants probably won't survive their winds.

Comment: I'm assuming that the wind blows from west to east across the face of the wall. Is this correct? Also - what kind of support for the climber are you planning on using and how are you planning to anchor it (for example, are you going to screw attachments into the wall and use wire for support? Use stakes next to the wall to hold up trellises?)

Comment: @black thumb_ Well i cant provide you with exact figures but for sure obviously nothing like mount washinton. You see, we have a semiarid climate so windy conditions are a norm and since the site is a bit exposed, you feel it a whole lot more then you would if your perhaps walking around town or something. It's not strong enough to blow away umbrellas but that's not to say that we don't get days when it does.

Comment: @jurp_ yes you are correct and for support, i plan or had planned on using stakes. i read somewhere that you don't need cement to hold it in place if you have clay soil like i have and that Gravel will do just fine but i believe wind wasn't taken into consideration. Anyway, its not the stakes that im actually worried about but the plant itself. I had a climbing rose in mind and with roses, wind protection is a must so im worried about the petals falling and blowing off prematurely as well as any new growth on the branches.

Comment: there is no such thing as normal wind conditions.